# Maven Central statistics & sonatype alternative

Tags: maven, sonatype, maven-central, maven-repository

What do the stats on [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central) mean and how do independent OSS developers publish their artifacts?

Disclaimer, I have been using Sonatype for years but I only stumbled over the Maven Central stats recently.

Looking at the stats for [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central), it claims to have 1.6M packages published this year, whereas [Atlassian is 100K, down from 1M in 2019](https://mvnrepository.com/repos/atlassian-packages-external) and [Sonatype has only about 5K, down from 500K in 2017](https://mvnrepository.com/repos/sonatype-releases). This makes me think Atlassian and especially Sonatype are "dying". The biggest contributor seems to be [JetBrain's KTor but even that is only 2/3 of what it was in 2022](https://mvnrepository.com/repos/space-public-ktor-eap).

When I search the web for ways to upload something to Maven Central, the only way to do this appears to be one of these two:

a) via oss.sonatype.org:

- [https://www.jetbrains.com/help/space/publish-artifacts-to-maven-central.html](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/space/publish-artifacts-to-maven-central.html#3ce0a35e)
- https://maven.apache.org/repository/guide-central-repository-upload.html (See section "Other Projects" for non-Apache projects)
- https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-publish-artifacts-to-maven-central
- https://blog.10pines.com/2018/06/25/publish-artifacts-on-maven-central/

b) or, if you are a big company, getting [your own hosted repository indexed by Maven Central](https://central.sonatype.org/publish/large-orgs/#next-steps)

I am aware that Sonatype appears to be managing Maven Central.

My questions:

1. Why does everyone advertise Sonatype but nobody uses it? [Even JetBrains advertises oss.sonatype.org](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/space/publish-artifacts-to-maven-central.html#3ce0a35e) despite having their own KTor? Do you always need a Sonatype account even if you are not publishing via Sonatype?
2. How do independent OSS projects publish their projects? Apparently it is not via the big known ones (Atlassian, Sonatype, KTor, Hortonworks, Spring, ...). The numbers don't seem to add up.
3. Is there something that I fundamentally misunderstand about what the Maven Central stats mean?

**EDIT** Fixed mentioning of Maven Central vs Maven Repository

Comment: First wrong assumption is that: https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central to be Maven Central which is wrong. This is central repository: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ furthermore this gives you search access: https://central.sonatype.com/search The central repository is used by a large number of projects (Apache Maven Project and also all other Apache Software Foundation project), Spring Project etc. A word about using it... If you consume something from Central (I mean: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) than you are downloading from Central repository ...

Comment: Also many OSS project distribute via central repository which is the simplest and best option...Those stats refer to the number of groupd/artifactId/ artifacts have been published but does not mean how many time a particular combination GAV has been downloaded ... I have written about that a bit https://blog.soebes.io/posts/2023/08/2023-08-06-download-statistics-for-maven/

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks,but I think that doesn´t change much, so the Stats are on MavenRepository, not Maven-Central (I'll fix that). The problem remains what the stats mean and how developers publish their artifacts. Your blog post is nice but Download stats are not relevant for this question.

Comment: That's not quite correct because Central repository is used by millions of devs... and it's the central location for all kind of artifacts... which means it is used massively... and neither Central nor Sonatype are "dying" ... on the contrary they are expanding....

Comment: @khmarbaise Sorry, this is really not what I'm asking (or claiming). I 100% agree that Maven is used my millions, probably increasingly, and Central is growing massively. My question is, where the new libraries and library updates **are coming from**, clearly they used to come from the Sonatype repo but not anymore. To phrase it differently, I am wondering about **upload** stats, not **download** stats. So measured on upload stats, Sonatype is really not doing very well, it is only 1% of what is used to be 6 years ago.